# Relation of parameter-dependent center manifold and parameter-independent center manifold

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Considering a parameter-dependent ODE

$\dot{x} = Ax + f_A(x,y,z,\mu) \\
\dot{y} = By + f_B(x,y,z,\mu) \\
\dot{z} = Cz + f_C(x,y,z,\mu) $

where A has only eigenvalues with zero real part, B only eigenvalues with negative real part and C has only eigenvalues with positive real part and such that $(x,y,z,\mu) \in \mathbb{R}^{n_0} \times\mathbb{R}^{n_-} \times\mathbb{R}^{n_+} \times\mathbb{R}^{p}$. Suppose the system has an equilibrium in $(x,y,z,\mu) = (0,0,0,0)$. From the center manifold theorem I know there exists a neighbourhood $U_{n_0} \subset \mathbb R^{n_0}$ of the origin and a $n_0$-dimensional center manifold $c: U_{n_0}\to \mathbb{R}^{n_-}\times \mathbb{R}^{n_+}$. 
The standard trick is to extend the system to

$\dot{x} = Ax + f_A(x,y,z,\mu) \\
\dot{\mu} = 0 \\
\dot{y} = By + f_B(x,y,z,\mu) \\
\dot{z} = Cz + f_C(x,y,z,\mu) $

and the center manifold theorem implies there exists neighbourhood $\mathbb{R}^{n_0} \times \mathbb{R}^{p}$ of the origin and a $n_0+p$-dimensional center manifold $\tilde{c}: U_{n_0} \times U_{p}\times \mathbb{R}^{p}  \to \mathbb{R}^{n_-}\times \mathbb{R}^{n_+}$.

My question is, how are $c$ and $\tilde{c}$ related? Is there a way to express $c$ in terms of $\tilde{c}$ or vice versa?

Comment: You are missing the main point: when you introduce a parameter depended center manifold you matrices $A,B,C$ usually change. Otherwise this "standard trick" would be a waist of time.

Comment: @Artem I think this is covered by letting $f_A$ and others to have non-zero derivatives at the origin. At least it was done this way in Shilnikov-Shilnikov-Turaev-Chua book, as far as I remember.

Comment: @Evgeny What book are you referring to? 
But there should be a relation between both center manifolds. In the first case you get a family of center manifolds (one for each parameter value) and in the second case you obtain a center manifold without the parameter. It seems natural, that there must be a relation between both center manifolds and I was hoping, somebody can shed some light into this matter.

Comment: I refer to [this book](https://labs.ni.gsu.edu/ashilnikov/pubs/part1.pdf). You might be interested in part of book around Theorem 5.2.